# Applescript enable-disable wifi Safari

Tags: wifi, safari, applescript

I figured out a command to enable/disable wifi.

```
networksetup -setairportpower en0 on
networksetup -setairportpower en0 off
```

Now, I was wondering how to combine it in AppleScript in a way that when Safari opens wifi is turned on and when Safari closes wifi is turned off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `EDITOR=nano crontab -e` and add a line like this:

`* * * * * pgrep -qx Safari&&networksetup -setairportpower en0 on||networksetup -setairportpower en0 off`

The command is only run once every minute though.

You could also save this plist as ~/Library/LaunchAgents/safariwifi.plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>safariwifi</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>bash</string>
    <string>-c</string>
    <string>while sleep 10;do pgrep -qx Safari&amp;&amp;mode=on||mode=off;[[ $last != $mode ]]&amp;&amp;networksetup -setairportpower en0 $mode;last=$mode;done</string>
  </array>
  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Then run `launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/safariwifi.plist`.

Comment: Thanks Lri

LaunchAgent script works great!

Can you please ask you for one more small modification of script to put condition to check and execute only if Mac is on battery?

Many thanks in advance!

Joe

Comment: Try using `while sleep 10;do if pgrep -qx Safari||pmset -g|grep -q 'AC Power.*\*$';then mode=on;else mode=off;fi;networksetup -setairportpower en0 $mode;done`.

Comment: Hi Laury, possibly help with this one http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/113519/disable-bluetooth-if-not-on-ac-plist ? It should be a second issue for a guru :-) Thanks in advance! Joe